# If statement, Android Studio with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, database-connection

So I am trying to send data back to my Firebase Database with only users that have signed up and logged in. I have written a code to send the data but i am trying to write an else if statement that a message in this case a Toast appears if they have not signed up. I am struggling to write a code for that.

```
private void sendScore() {

    String userName = name.getText().toString();
    String userScore = BenchScore.getText().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(userName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userScore)) {

        String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();

        ScoreProfile scoreProfile = new ScoreProfile(id, userName, userScore);

        databaseReference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).setValue(scoreProfile);
        name.setText("");
        BenchScore.setText("");

    } else if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().) {
        Toast.makeText(Score.this, "You need to sign up in order to use this", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if an user is logged in you can use :

```
...
else if( FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null ) 
     {
     // Call your toast here
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace ur code with this one:

```
private void sendScore() {

    String userName = name.getText().toString();
    String userScore = BenchScore.getText().toString();

    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userScore)){

        String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();

        ScoreProfile scoreProfile = new ScoreProfile(id, userName, userScore);

        databaseReference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).setValue(scoreProfile);
        name.setText("");
        BenchScore.setText("");

    } else if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid() == null) {
        Toast.makeText(Score.this, "You need to sign up in order to use this", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I've just included a check for whether `getUid()` is non null in the `if` statement and in `else if`, I've checked whether `getUid()` is null. This would serve your purpose, hopefully.